# Go build cannot find package

Tags: go

## Problem

I haven't been able to find a solution to this by looking at related questions. I can't tell what makes my Go environment different from the canonical setup.

`go env` returns

```
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="386"
GOCHAR="8"
GOOS="linux"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

`tree $GOPATH` returns

```
/home/USER/go
├── bin
├── pkg
│   └── linux_386
│       └── bitbucket.org
│           └── USER-NAME
│               └── PROJECT
│                   └── my_package.a
└── src
    └── bitbucket.org
        └── USER-NAME
            └── PROJECT
                ├── main
                │   ├── main.go
                └── my_package
                    └── my_package.go
```

(ALL-CAPS are substitutions)

main.go contains

```
package main

import (
        "bitbucket.org/USER-NAME/PROJECT/my_package"
)

func main() {
        my_package.Foo()
}
```

Calling `go build` in the `main` directory returns `import "my_package": cannot find package`

Volker pointed out that `go env` should have returned a `GOPATH` entry as well. [The source of the env command](http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/env.go) corroborates that. However, running `echo $GOPATH` in bash or `os.Getenv("GOPATH")` in Go both return `\home\USER\go`. I'm not sure why the same isn't returned by `go env`.

## Solution

I was running Go 1.0 when I was having this issue. The problem disappeared when I upgraded to Go 1.2.1.

Comment: What is the output from `go version`?

Comment: `go version` outputs `go version go1`, which is a bit ambiguous. However, I installed it with `sudo apt-get install golang` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and that version is up to date, so according to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/golang) it looks like it's only version 1.0. I'll try getting a more recent version.

Comment: Yes, it's Go version 1.0.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak If you manage to install a later version of Go, let us know. You can use something like https://github.com/moovweb/gvm to simplify it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Installing Go 1.2.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have a directory called main. This won't work. Change it.

Structure it like `$GOPATH/src/bitbucket.com/youruser name/yourpackagename/{main.go, otherthing.go, otherpackagedirectory}`.

"package main" doesn't have to be in it's own sub folder: it inherits the name of your Bitbucket project (username/myprojectname).

Comment: I structured it as you suggested but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you absolutely confirmed that the shell session/application you are calling `go build` also has the correct `$GOPATH`? (i.e. you're not calling it from different shell sessions or tmux panes, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that `$GOPATH` has the correct value where I'm calling `go build`.

Answer (score -4):

You did not set (or export) `GOPATH`. GOPATH Is much more important than GOROOT (at least in newe Go versions).

Comment: If that were the case, then `tree $GOPATH` would not have worked. (Well, I guess it would if I were in that directory at the time, but that wasn't the case.) Anyway, I have `$GOPATH` set to `$HOME/go` in my `.profile`.

Comment: If it would have been set, it would have been shown in the output of `go env`. Thus: You have no GOPATH.

Comment: Interesting. [The source of the command](http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/env.go) supports what you're saying, but `echo $GOPATH` returns `/home/USER/go`. Any idea why that would happen? I'll try running `os.Getenv("GOPATH")` myself now.

Comment: When I run `os.Getenv("GOPATH")` myself I get `/home/USER/go`.